# ROR – Post data to a database on visit of a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, web, backend

New to backend development and RoR in particualar.

I created a db migration, which adds new field to existing db.

How can I post data into this field, when specific URL is visited (for example datetime of that visit)? I guess, I have to write that logics in appropriate controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can put this logic in the controller.

In below example we record the `DateTime` and `user_id` using devise with model `User`

```
def show
  Visit.create(user_id: current_user.id, visited_at: DateTime.now)
end
```

The corresponding migration is:

```
create_table :visits do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.datetime :visited_at
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But what if I've already made migration, which adds field to existing table? Like the following:
  def change
    add_column :users, :url_visited_at, :datetime
  end

So in this case would be enough to edit existing migration or it is necessary to create new one?

Comment: What is the table name and field name ? Can you show your migration ?

Comment: Table name: items (table exists already)

My mig only adds new field to the existing table and is the following (dunno, why Ctrl+K is not working):

     `class AddVisitedAtToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]`
       `def change`
         `add_column :items, :item_visited_at, :datetime`
       `end`
     `end`

Comment: The visits should be store in a different table, if an item can be visited multiple times. Create a table :visits, and put a relationship between :items and :visits

Comment: Got it. But, for example, how would it be in case, if item can be visited once?

Comment: I assume your item is created before it is visited. So the item exists and the item_visited_at is `nil` initially. Then put this in controller action for visit:  `Item.find(params[:id]).update(item_visited_at: DateTime.now)`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant!